# Why am I getting "this.log is not a function" when running sfdx CLI commands?

Tags: salesforcedx

I've installed the sfdx CLI utility but I cannot actually run any commands, as anything I try I get the following error:

> !   this.log is not a
>   function

This seems to be some sort of Javascript issue with my workstation but I can't seem to figure out what could be causing it.

I'm on the following versions:

- node 8.9.4 (downgraded from 8.11 in case that was the issue - it
  wasn't)
- npm 5.6.0
- sfdx-cli/6.38.0 (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4
- Windows 10 enterprise v.1803

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Do you get any output from `sfdx plugins --core`? If so, what are the results?

Comment: Yep - `@salesforce/plugin-generator 0.0.10 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 1.0.8 (core)
builtins 1.0.0 (core)
salesforcedx 44.5.0 (core)`

Comment: Okay, your DX is definitely up to date, then. You mentioned deprecated plugins, though: what's `sfdx plugins` show?

Comment: !    no plugins installed

Comment: I ran `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest` and now I'm showing `salesforcedx 44.5.0` when I run `sfdx plugins` but still getting the error.  Are there other plugins I need to install?

Comment: Okay, we probably need to see your log file. What's the last few lines of `c:\users\your.name\.sfdx\sfdx.log`? There might be something in there we can use to triage. See also [log files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_log_messages.htm) for how to set a logging level to try and get more relevant information. If you see anything amiss (there should be errors in there), it might help get to the bottom of the mystery.

Comment: I had to set it to TRACE but then finally got some diagnostic info.  The last entry is `{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"3QD46M2","pid":10484,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'create' logger instance","time":"2018-11-09T13:51:26.599Z","v":0}` but there are a bunch of different `Setup xxx logger instance` messages before that, along with various `cmdDecorator` messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in another post and it was answered by @kevin-p here: [SFDX: this.log is not a function when running create commands](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242534/sfdx-this-log-is-not-a-function-when-running-create-commands)

His answer was:

> If you find a file .yo-rc.json in your project root, or any folder above it rename or delete that .yo-rc.json file, and you'll be good to go. In my case, the file was in my ~ folder. Even though my code was in ~/Code/helloWorldLWC the presence of that file in my home directory caused the self.log is not a function error.

Comment: Amazing - that fixed it.  I didn't even remember running Yeoman at first but now I do.  I would have never thought to look into that.  Thanks!