# SFDX: this.log is not a function when running create commands

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

If i run this command `sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc --componentname TEST_LWC --outputdir force-app/main/default/lwc`

I get this error message:

`this.log is not a function`

This is not unique this command though, I also get this error message when trying to create apex classes, lightning components and create a project with a manifest.

`sfdx -v`

`sfdx-cli/6.44.0-dead729fb5 (darwin-x64) node-v8.11.4`

`sfdx plugins --core`

`@salesforce/plugin-generator 1.0.1 (core)`
`@salesforce/sfdx-trust 1.0.8 (core)`
`builtins 1.0.0 (core)`
`salesforcedx 45.0.9 (pre-release)`

This is what gets logged in my sfdx.log file (I cleared out the file before running the command)

{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'cmdRegistry' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.601Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'cmdDecorator' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.602Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"alias:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.685Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"alias:set","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.690Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"alias (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.690Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:execute","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.707Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:log:get","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.711Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:log:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.714Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:log:tail","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.718Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:test:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.722Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:test:run","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.726Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.727Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"auth:jwt:grant","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.770Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"auth:logout","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.774Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"auth:sfdxurl:store","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.778Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"auth:web:login","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.782Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"auth (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.782Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"config:get","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.788Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"config:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.795Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"config:set","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.798Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"config (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.798Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:bulk:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.804Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:bulk:status","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.808Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:bulk:upsert","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.810Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:record:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.813Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:record:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.816Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:record:get","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.820Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:record:update","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.822Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:soql:query","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.825Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:tree:export","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.828Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data:tree:import","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.832Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"data (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.832Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"doc:commands:display","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.838Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"doc:commands:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.841Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"doc (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.841Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:test:install","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.847Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:test:run","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.851Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.851Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"limits:api:display","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.857Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"limits (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.857Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:convert","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.862Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:deploy","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:04.865Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'AppHub' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:06.765Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:deploy:cancel","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.214Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:deploy:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.219Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'SchemaValidator' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.222Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'SchemaValidator' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.223Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:retrieve","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.226Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi:retrieve:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.229Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"mdapi (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.229Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.237Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.241Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:display","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.243Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.246Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:open","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.248Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:shape:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.251Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:shape:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.254Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:shape:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.257Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:snapshot:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.260Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:snapshot:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.262Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:snapshot:get","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.265Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org:snapshot:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.267Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"org (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.268Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.313Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:hammertest:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.321Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:hammertest:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.326Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:hammertest:run","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.333Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:install","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.336Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:install:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.339Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:installed:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.342Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.345Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:uninstall","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.349Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:uninstall:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.353Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:update","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.356Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.360Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:create:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.363Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:create:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.366Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.369Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:promote","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.372Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:report","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.376Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package:version:update","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.378Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.379Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package1:version:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.424Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package1:version:create:get","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.427Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package1:version:display","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.431Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package1:version:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.434Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"package1 (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.434Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"project:upgrade","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.439Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"project (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.439Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"schema:sobject:describe","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.472Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"schema:sobject:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.476Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"schema (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.477Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:convert","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.482Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:delete","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.887Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:deploy","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.895Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:open","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.899Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:pull","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.902Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:push","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.907Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:retrieve","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.914Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source:status","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.916Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"source (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.916Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.921Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user:display","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.924Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user:list","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.927Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user:password:generate","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.930Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user:permset:assign","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.932Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"user (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.933Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"visualforce (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:07.935Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'SchemaValidator' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:12.547Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'SchemaValidator' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:12.547Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:class:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.072Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex:trigger:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.073Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"apex (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.073Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"visualforce:component:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.073Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"visualforce:page:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"visualforce (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:app:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:component:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:event:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:interface:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.074Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning:test:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.075Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"lightning (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.075Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"project:create","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.075Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"log":"cmdDecorator","level":10,"msg":"project (main topic)","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:13.075Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Benjamins-Air","pid":7806,"level":10,"msg":"Setup 'lightning:component:create' logger instance","time":"2018-12-13T20:34:14.731Z","v":0}

Comment: Are you running across or on a flash drive?

Comment: No, I am running this directly on my MacBook Air, MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue a few days back. In my situation, it was a yoeman config file that was throwing things off.

If you find a file `.yo-rc.json` in your project root, ***or any folder above it*** rename or delete that `.yo-rc.json` file, and you'll be good to go. In my case, the file was in my `~` folder. Even though my code was in `~/Code/helloWorldLWC` the presence of that file in my home directory caused the `self.log is not a function` error.